# GraalVM Python Restrict Import Certain Modules

Tags: graalvm, graalpython

I am using GraalVM Python in my project https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/python/

How do I restrict guest Python code from importing critical modules like "os" module, but still allow them to import safe whitelisted modules like sdk/utils/SafeModule.py and other like numpy, pandas etc?